# mysql_select_db failure

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-select-db

I am using phpMyAdmin + MySQL.

I created a database and am now trying to make the connection in a PHP script. The curious thing is that connecting to the DB works, so I get the "Connected to MySQL server" message,  but I when it comes to selecting the 'petfood' database, the script shows "DIED at selection".

Any idea why? Thanks, and here's my piece of code:

```
<?php

$user = 'localhost';
$pass = 'password';
$db_name = 'petfood';

$db_conn = new mysqli("localhost", $user, $pass, $db_name) or die("Cannot connect to DB");
echo "Connected to MySQL server";
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("DIED at selection");
echo "Database Selected";

?>
```

Comment: Use PDO or Mysqli instead

Comment: I think you're suppose to pass your `$db_conn` as a second parameter to `mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_conn);`

Comment: You're mixing APIs, you can't do that. Stick with one.

Comment: You are mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`.

Comment: It's redundant anyways, since you're passing the `$db_name` in your initial connection.

Comment: Stick with [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo), huh @Fred-ii-? ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard uh-huh ♫ uh-huh ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spot the difference:

```
$db_conn = new mysqli("localhost", $user, $pass, $db_name) or die("Cannot connect to DB");
                    ^----

mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("DIED at selection");
     ^---
```

If you had proper debugging, you'd have been told about the problem:

```
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Never output a fixed (useless) error message when you can have the system TELL you what's wrong.

Comment: Also no need for select_db since the database is being passed to the original object, but use PDO anyway. mysql_* is old, deprecated as of 5.5, and PDO is just, well, better. Prepared statements are much cleaner and prevent sql injection.

Comment: zgr: mysqli has prepared statements as well. mysqli v.s. pdo  is purely a preference choice.

Comment: that is true.. I was referring to mysql_*, not mysqli. In either case, yes it is a preference and OP is mixing the 2. Good catch.

Answer (score -2):

1: using mysql

`$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db("examples",$dbhandle) or die("Could not select examples");
$query = "SELECT name FROM mytable" ;
$result = mysqli_query($query);`

2: using mysqli

`$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
$query = "SELECT name FROM mytable" ;
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);`

Comment: `mysql_` is deprecated and should not be used, you forgot about PDO, and you failed to state what the actual problem with the code in the question is.

Comment: two? How about three? You forgot PDO completely.